How to avoid showing anyio.WouldBlock errors in middleware?
Description
I have a similar issue as in https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/10387, but upgrading fastapi and starlette did not fix my issue
When the app fails, instead of seeing an error entry in the logs, I see a succession of logs that I don't understand. This is a problem for me because from a monitoring perspective, my app only raises WouldBlock errors
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/streams/memory.py", line 94, in receive return self.receive_nowait() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/streams/memory.py", line 89, in receive_nowait raise WouldBlock"
anyio.WouldBlock
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 399, in run_asgi result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 70, in __call__ return await self.app(scope, receive, send) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 1054, in __call__ await super().__call__(scope, receive, send) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 123, in __call__ await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 186, in __call__ raise exc File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 164, in __call__ await self.app(scope, receive, _send) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 191, in __call__ response = await self.dispatch_func(request, call_next) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ynstant_utils/middlewares/middlewares.py", line 61, in middleware return await call_next(request) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 165, in call_next raise app_exc File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 151, in coro await self.app(scope, receive_or_disconnect, send_no_error) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 191, in __call__ response = await self.dispatch_func(request, call_next) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ynstant_utils/middlewares/middlewares.py", line 55, in other_middleware response = await call_next(request) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 165, in call_next raise app_exc File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 151, in coro await self.app(scope, receive_or_disconnect, send_no_error) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 191, in __call__ response = await self.dispatch_func(request, call_next) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ynstant_utils/middlewares/middlewares.py", line 49, in another_middleware return await call_next(request) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 165, in call_next raise app_exc File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 151, in coro await self.app(scope, receive_or_disconnect, send_no_error) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 85, in __call__ await self.app(scope, receive, send) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 65, in __call__ await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app raise exc File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app await app(scope, receive, sender) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 756, in __call__ await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 776, in app await route.handle(scope, receive, send) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 297, in handle await self.app(scope, receive, send) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 77, in app await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, request)(scope, receive, send) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app raise exc File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app await app(scope, receive, sender) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 72, in app response = await func(request) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 278, in app raw_response = await run_endpoint_function( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 191, in run_endpoint_function return await dependant.call(**values)
Finally i see the logs that I expect, showing the trace from my application, in the last entry above
Operating System
Linux and Mac
Operating System Details
FastAPI Version
0.111.0
Pydantic Version
1.10.11
Python Version
3.10.13
